# Can Javascript detect that a POST operation is completed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, drupal

I am working with a Chrome extension, which is intended to give the user a bit more control over the navigation between pages in our University's adaptation of the Drupal CMS. One of the things which I wish to be able to influence is where a page navigates after a Save operation has been carried out. Saves are handled by `<form>` elements which use POST method and have their `action` attributes set to the URL of the same page as the present. However, depending on which type the present page is, the Save operation (clicking the `<input type="submit">` element) will cause navigation to another page, or for the page to remain at the same location. I wish that the user should be able to select which page to navigate to after saving by choosing an option from a `<select>` element that I have added in the extension. That causes a chrome.storage object to store the desired destination URL which is then retrieved inside a `window.addEventListener("beforeunload")` function whereupon a `window.location.href = <desired URL>`is executed. In order for the saved content to be displayed, the page also has to be reloaded.

The problem for me, working from client side only, is to know when to direct to the selected location. If it happens too soon, the Save operation is not completed. If it happens too late, the default page has time to get loaded, and time is lost. I have managed to make it work provisionally by inserting a `setTimeout()` function, but the timeout interval is of course arbitrary and could fail depending on a lot of circumstances. Is there a way to detect within the js script that the POST operation is complete and that it is now safe to load a new page?

Present code:

HTML

```html
<select class="my-selector">
  <option value="URL1">page 1</option>
  <option value="URL2">page 2</option>
  <!--etc -->
</select>
```

JS

```
 $(".my-selector").change(function(){
      var url = $(this).val();
      chrome.storage.sync.set({redirect:true,url:url})
      $(this).closest("form").submit();
 });

    //=============

    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
       chrome.storage.sync.get(function(message){
          if(message.redirect){
            chrome.storage.sync.set({redirect:false,reload:true});
            setTimeout(function(){ //this I want to avoid
              window.location.href = message.url;
            },3000);  
          }
        })
      });

    //=============

$(document).ready(function(){
      chrome.storage.sync.get(function(message){
          if(message.reload){
            chrome.storage.sync.set({reload:false});
            location.reload();
          }
      });
     //etc
 });
```

Comment: I guess you can do it thus: 1) listen to the `submit` event and stop it via preventDefault, 2) use XMLHttpRequest or fetch with FormData API to submit the form explicitly, 3) since it's your request you know when it finishes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer does not provide a way to  detect that a POST operation is completed – rather it hijacks the post operation using AJAX. But it accomplishes the task I had in mind, namely to separate the sending of the form data from the navigation to the next page.
 Building on the excellent advice from [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875/woxxom)'s comment, I have got the following procedure to work, using the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) and jQuery `$.post()` operation. I don't know if it is optimal – is there maybe a more straightforward way to create the `formObj` object? Any suggestions welcome.

HTML

```
<select class="my-selector">
  <option value="URL1">page 1</option>
  <option value="URL2">page 2</option>
  <!--etc -->
</select>
```

JS

```
$(".my-selector").change(function(){
   var link = $(this).val();
   var myForm = $(this).closest("form").get(0);//select the form
   var url = $(myForm).attr("action");
   var formData = new FormData(myForm);//use FormData API to extract the data to send
   var formObj = {};
   for(var pair of formData.entries()){
      formObj[pair[0]] = pair[1];//create the object to send the data with
   }
   $.post(url,formObj,function(){ //send the data without submitting the form
      window.location.href = link; //redirect to desired location
   });
 });
```